# Passando o "this" para classes inicializadas dentro de outra classe em TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

## INTRO:

Sou relativamente novo no TypeScript (poucas semanas de pratica), estou aprendendo aos poucos o superset e utilizando ele em conjunto ao Electron. Estava fazendo um **extend** da classe **BrowserWindow** para criar funcionalidades extras e portando parte do meu código antigo em JS puro para o TypeScript, quando surgiu uma duvida, possivelmente por alguma pratica ruim ou por o TS não aceitar minha logica ...

## DUVIDA:

Estou inicializando outras classes dentro da classe na qual dou o **extend** do **BrowserWindow**:

(o snippet é só para exemplificar o código, já que ele vai retornar erro);

```js
class Worker extends BrowserWindow {

    public mouse: Mouse = new Mouse(this);   

    constructor(options: object) {
      super(options);
    
    }
};
```

ela leva como argumento o **this** que seria a classe "pai" para ter acesso direto a todas as funcionalidades do **Worker** e do **BrowserWindow** tais como **.getBounds()** que retorna a area da janela no monitor do usuário.

Porem, ao passar o **this** para a classe **Mouse** eu não faço ideia da forma correta de declarar ela dentro da classe, qual tipo eu devo usar, ou a forma correta de fazer isso, a ideia é não extender mais a classe.

(Novamente, snippet somente para exemplificação do código)

```js
export class Mouse extends Steering  {    
    
    // Qual tipo devo declarar a variavel???
    public window: ???;     
    
    // Qual tipo devo passar o parametro ???
    constructor (window: ???) {           
        
        super (new Vector(0, 0));           

        this.window = window;        

    }
}
```

Passando o tipo **any** para o argumento **window** o compilador compila sem erros, mas eu deixo de ter uma das maiores qualidades do TypeScript, pois qualquer código errado que eu escreva ele vai passar sem validação.

Qual seria a forma correta de passar o **this** para a minha classe **Mouse**?  Qual tipo eu utilizo? Minha logica está incorreta?

Grato!

Comment: Cara tenta usar any ou Object. Não testei para ver se funciona

Comment: Eu ja tentei... e ainda não consigo acessar os métodos da classe "pai", alem de me retornar um erro de compilação ...

Comment: Qual erro de compilação que retorna?